# Updating sqlite data in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an Android app which basically shows locations on map. I plan to store location related data locally in sqlite.
But I also need to update app data periodically as either I would be collecting more data manually by myself or would enable app users to send me the new data by email which I can then update in my app data.Bottom-line is that at intervals I need to update my application data so that users can have as many locations as possible.

I want to know how can I periodically update app data?Do I need to periodically run scripts in my application which pick up new data and dump it in sqlite?
Or, storing data in sqlite is a wrong approach and storing data on server side is better?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is only needed locally, or will be shared via email (I am not sure why you would do that), then it is ok to keep it in Sqlite database. But if it needs to be shared among users, then it either needs to be stored on a server, or you need to have a mechanism for synchronizing data between users.
As for periodically updating app data. You are writing the app, and you have full control over the data that you are putting in the DB, so dump that data somewhere at time intervals, or use event handlers to trigger when to dump the data.

Comment: Thanks Avezou.  email option is there because I am a one team member and hence doing all field work for data collection may not be easy.So I plan to provide a feature in app which user can use to send new data to me via email.